# array updates in delay on checkbox click

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

im trying to create an array of user premissions, which can be controled by a set of checkboxes.
when i check a box and `console.log()` the array it looks just fine with all the premissions i checked, but when i uncheck the box, the `console.log()` returns the previus array value and it will be ubdated only on the next click

```
  const [prems, setPrems] = useState([]);

  const handleCheckbox = (e) => {
    let arr = prems
    if (e.target.checked) {
      arr.push(e.target.value)
      setPrems(arr)
      console.log(prems) //shwos the array with all the checked values
    } else {
      let newArr = arr.filter((item) => {
        return item !== e.target.value
      })
      setPrems(newArr)
      console.log(prems) //shows the array still with the value i unchecked
    }
  };
```

*the event on the checkboxes is onChange and it works the same with onClick*

Comment: Hi, Yuval as I can see you are trying to console state. If you don't know let me tell you that state is async so it logs the previous value.
If you update state and want to console you can use useEffect dependency and put value of your state into it and also can console inside useEffect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React state [is set asynchronously](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). So you can't rely on the state right after updating it.

In order to look for the changes of that state, it is better to put it inside a `useEffect` hook and set the variable name as the dependency:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  // the prems have changed
}, [prems]);
```

Also you have a big mistake in your code:

```
let arr = prems
if (e.target.checked) {
  arr.push(e.target.value)
...
```

Here, you are assigning the `prems` variable to `arr` and mutating the `arr` variable. THEY REFERENCE THE SAME OBJECT! So pushing everything to `arr` will also push it to `prems` and vice versa. Never do that. Read more about JS objects [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics).

UPDATE: This is the correct code:

```
const handleCheckbox = (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      setPrems([ ...prems, e.target.value ])
    } else {
      const newPrems = prems.filter((item) => item !== e.target.value);
      setPrems(newPrems)
    }
};

React.useEffect(() => {
  // do something
}, [prems]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reliably update the state using [Functional updates in `useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates):

```
const [prems, setPrems] = useState({});

const handleCheckbox = (e) => {
  setPrems((prevState) => {
    return { ...prevState, [e.target.value]: e.target.checked };
  });
};
```

As @ Kamlesh sharma noted, state is async, so logging may not show the current state. You could instead render the `prems` as follows to see the current state:

```
<ul>
  {Object.keys(prems).map((prem) => {
    if (prems[prem]) {
      return <li key={prem}>{prem}</li>;
    }
  })}
</ul>
```

You can view the code in action with checkboxes [in this JSFiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71264045/array-updates-in-delay-on-checkbox-click).

**EDIT:**

If it is particularly important that `prems` be an array rather than an object, the `setPrems` call can be modified as follows:

```
setPrems((prevState) => {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    return [...prevState, e.target.value];
  } else {
    return prevState.filter((elem) => elem !== e.target.value);
  }
});
```