# setState in useEffect not update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

Got an input and want to pass value to handler:

```
const [term, setTerm] = useState('');

<Input type="text" onBlur={(e)=>handleFilter(e, 'params')} />

const handleFilter = async(e, params) => {
//... api call and etc
setTerm(e.target.value); // update term
console.log(term) // return none-updated value! but I need fresh value
// send this value to another api
}
```

I want to make an search filter function, for ex. if I enter `a`, console return empty, then I enter `b` console return `a` ! it means `term` not update immediately, then I used `useEffect` but inside the `useEffect` I got new value, but inside `handleFilter` function still console return prev value.

```
useEffect(() => {
    getApi()
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
        })

    console.log(term) // works fine, return new value
    setTerm(term) // update term

}, [term])
```

I tried this but no success:

```
setTerm({...term, e.target.value});
```

Any solution? I'm new to react hook.

Comment: you can also try: `ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates(() => { ... })` to batch state updates

Answer (score 1):

You can check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71264045/array-updates-in-delay-on-checkbox-click/71270116#71270116).

This is because react's state update is async. You can't rely on its update right after calling `setState`. Put your effects (code that is run after a state is updated) in a `useEffect` hook.

```
const handleFilter = async(e, params) => {
  //... api call and etc
  setTerm(e.target.value); // update term
}

React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log(term) // return none-updated value! but I need fresh value
  // send this value to another api
}, [term]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTerm` is async and will update the `term` on the next render cycle.
it is not updated immediately for the current render cycle.
you can store the current value in a ref if you are curious what is happening behind the scenes

```
const termRef = React.useRef(term);
termRef.current = term;
const yourHandler = () => {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(termRef.current), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we are going ahead with useEffect with an API call, please ensure to include async await scenario to ensure that `setState` updates after the data is fetched.

```
useEffect(async () => {
    const data = await getApi()
      

    console.log(term) // works fine, return new value
    setTerm(term) // update term

}, [term])
```

Comment: you can't mark the callback function from useEffect as async

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. I should created a new async function and should have called it here passing function as dependency.

Comment: I could have gone with IIFE here right?

Comment: you could go with an IIFE, though creating and calling the async function looks a bit cleaner

Answer (score -1):

I could be wrong on this one, but could this have something to do with you calling an `async` function from a normal event. This might cause some type of delay.

There is also the fast that `useEffect` is treated differently in React than a normal function, since it's integrated into React.

It could also be related to the `[term]` trigger in the `useEffect` but the event in your `handleFilter` isn't treated the same

Comment: Dont post an answer if your not sure about it.